# AngularJS : Synchronize multiple independent promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i'm working on an AngularJS app where Factories (that query the DB) returns promises.

The call to those Factories are encapsulated in functions such as :

```
function getUsers(id) { 
    MyUserFactory.getUsers(id).then(function(data) { 
        $scope.mydata = data;
        ...lot of code...
    })
}

function updateAcordingToUserAndWeatherOfTheDay(day) {
    MyWeatherFactory.getWeather(day).then(function(data) {
        if ($scope.mydata.likesRain) {
             ...
        }
   })
}
```

then I have a :

```
getUser(42); updateAcordingToUserAndWeatherOfTheDay(monday);
```

Obviously, this works one out of two time, if the async query done by `getUser()` didn't had time to complete I get an error in `updateAcordingToUserAndWeatherOfTheDay()` on the `$scope.mydata.likesRain`

I know I could chain the `.then()` to force one query to wait for the other but 
this refactoring would take a lot of time I don't have right now.

Is there another way I can wait for a promise to be completed ? At least to temporary fix the bug before a refactoring. Now the solution we have is a 3 second timer...

Comment: 3 second timer = worst solution ever when you could just replace that timer by returning the promise where you need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refactoring this is very simple, just have the method `return` the promise.

```
function getUsers(id) { 
    return MyUserFactory.getUsers(id).then(function(data) { 
        $scope.mydata = data;
        ...lot of code...
    })
}

function updateAcordingToUserAndWeatherOfTheDay(day) {
    return MyWeatherFactory.getWeather(day).then(function(data) {
        if ($scope.mydata.likesRain) {
             ...
        }
   })
}

getUsers(42).then(function() { updateAcordingToUserAndWeatherOfTheDay(day); });
```

This doesn't have to change any existing code (because returning the promise doesn't break any existing infrastructure), other than the code that you need to modify.

This is the fastest way to refactor to make it work.

Comment: This looks exactly what I was searching for !!! Thank you
I try it and accept your answer as soon as the cooldown is over :)

Comment: if there is an error in getUsers(), how can I break the promise chain properly ?

Comment: finished fiddle and found this answer ><
@IggY: if your getUser is rejecting promise, then second function won't get called because it is in the resolve path. You can handle the error (print error msg) by adding a second function in .then()

Comment: `properly` all depends on what you want to do if there's an error in `getUsers`. `.then` takes (at least) two parameters, the first function is called on `success` of the promise, the second function is called on `error` (when the previous promise returns a promise that is, or gets, rejected). Simply add a second callback method to your `.then` function wherever you want to check for an error.

Answer (score 1):

`.then()` is probably the right way to go. Other solution using callbacks:

```
function getUsers(id, callback) { 
    MyUserFactory.getUsers(id).then(function(data) { 
        $scope.mydata = data;
        ...lot of code...
        if (typeof callback === "function") {
            callback();
        }
    })
}

getUser(42, function() {
    updateAcordingToUserAndWeatherOfTheDay(monday);
});
```